# Python itertools.combinations continue from certain value?

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools, brute-force

I used itertools to generate all combinations or printable ascii chars:

```
for combo in product('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c', repeat=10):
```

However, script was interrupted, but i got last sequence string. Is there a way to continue generation values using this string as starting sequence? Thank you.

UPD: I trying to solve some CTF task, by bruteforcing XOR cipher text. Xortool's output:

```
 2:   11.2%
   5:   15.6%
   7:   11.2%
  10:   18.4%
  15:   9.6%
  18:   6.6%
  20:   12.1%
  25:   5.8%
  30:   5.5%
  40:   4.0%
```

I can't see other solution now, at lest will try to bf 5-byte keys.

Comment: Also, that's one *huge* search space you are trying to generate. How much time have you got? I mean, even if you can check 1 million combinations per second, you'd still need 2 million years to check them all.

Comment: I hope it will be 3-4 days or something. But in the end I've got a lot of time. So if I can't continue, then i must look for another approach, what would you suggest?

Comment: @user3416803: it'll take millions of years, even on the fastest computers. This is why a 10-character random password is secure.

Comment: This question is a poster child for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem - OP, maybe now would be a good time for you to tell us **what is the real problem you're trying to solve?**

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm pretty sure you could do this faster than that. [At a mere billion permutations per second it'll only take 2 millenia.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=97+%5E+10+%2F+1e9Hz) My *laptop* does 20m/s; 50x that is much less than "the fastest computers".

Comment: @Veedrac I was assuming there'd be more work than just generating the tuple and discarding it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the last string that was processed started with the character `'5'`. Then you can ignore all strings that started with previous characters, and set up the iteration like so:

```
for start in ('567...'):
    for subcombo in product('01234567...', repeat=9):
        yield (start,) + subcombo
```

However you really can't get through this search space. It's easy to calculate the total number of combinations:

```
>>> len('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c') ** 10
73742412689492826049L
```

While even if you could process a billion combinations a second, you wouldn't get close in a year:

```
>>> 1000000000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
31536000000000000
```

Comment: I see, thanks. But it seems like I need to find another approach.

Answer (score 2):

OK, look, this question doesn't really make sense because you have a loop which will probably run longer than your computer will, but I have an answer for you anyway!

Your loop produces tuples like this:

```
('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'C', '!', 'D')
```

Let's say that's the last one you saw on your previous run.  So write your code like this:

```
resume_target = ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', 'C', '!', 'D')
sequence = product(all_those_letters, repeat=10)
for combo in sequence:
    if combo == resume_target:
        break

for combo in sequence:
    # now do whatever you'd normally do
```

What I've done here is to simply "fast forward" with minimal computation through the first however-many combos were previously processed.  This is simple and should be correct, but it does assume that you do a signficant amount of work with each combo--otherwise it's pointless to fast forward because you could just do a trivial amount of work over again.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be fast but with [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) you can skip the first n of them:

```
c = itertools.islice(itertools.product('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c', repeat=10), 5, None)
c.next()
Out[39]: ('0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5')
```